# Access to Jenkins frontend in AWS Private subnet with NACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, acl, private-subnet

I have a Jenkins instance in a private subnet with a load balancer in front of it, also in a private subnet. My question is, how do I grant access to Jenkins frontend only when I am on the VPN. I know I can put the load balancer in a public subnet but I want to limit access to Jenkins only to users that are on the VPN while it is in a private subnet. Can this be done with NACL and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

A VPN connection allows you to make a secure connection to your VPC. Over VPN you should be able to access your private resources like a private load balancer or private subnet instances. So you just need to set up the VPN connection try to add the security group rules to access the Jenkins console.